# C# how find the extra ) or ( parentheses in string, and replace them with @

Tags: c#

C# how find the extra `)` or `(` parentheses in string, and replace them with `@`

sample input

```
)(more)))
((((more)))
((((more))
(about)((index)(more)))
(about)((index)(more)())
(about)(((index)(more)
(about)(((index)(more
(about)(((index)(more)))))
```

sample output

```
@(more)@@
@(((more)))
@@((more))
(about)((index)(more))@
(about)((index)(more)())
(about)@@(index)(more)
(about)@@(index)@more
(about)(((index)(more)))@@
```

Comment: So each *line* is self-contained? As in each line should have a balanced set of brackets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice twist on a classic problem. As with any bracket-matching problem, we need to keep a stack of unmatched open brackets, and clear them when we find a corresponding close bracket.

Nice job on the examples in the question - they were very helpful in figuring out what the exact behaviour should be.

```
public static string BalanceBrackets(string input)
{
    // First, we'll do a straight pass through the string. Every time we find a '(', we'll
    // record it in a stack. Every time we find a ')', we'll check whether there's a
    // corresponding '(' in the stack: if there is, we'll pop it; if there isn't, we've
    // got an unmatched ')' and we'll replace it with a '@'.
    // When we're done, any unmatched '('s will be in the stack. Replace each of these with
    // a '@'.

    char[] chars = input.ToCharArray();

    // Positions of all unmatched open parens
    var unmatchedOpens = new Stack<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
    {
        if (chars[i] == '(')
        {
            unmatchedOpens.Push(i);
        }
        else if (chars[i] == ')')
        {
            if (unmatchedOpens.Count > 0)
            {
                unmatchedOpens.Pop();   
            }
            else
            {
                chars[i] = '@'; 
            }
        }
    }

    while (unmatchedOpens.Count > 0)
    {
        int pos = unmatchedOpens.Pop();
        chars[pos] = '@';
    }

    return new string(chars);
}
```

[See it in action](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1X9fup)